# Subspace of vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

The question goes as follows:

Let $x$ be a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ written as a column, and define

$$U = (Ax : A \in M_{(mn)}) $$

Show that $U$ is a subspace of $R^m$

I know the three things we test for are if $0 \in U$ and then closure under addition and scalar multiplication but I don't really know how to go about this in the right way.

I'm not sure but I believe that $x$ is a fixed column matrix in this case.

I know the zero vector is in $\mathbb{R}^m$ but how do I go about showing it's also in $U$?

My understanding so far is that U is composed of $Ax$ and that if $A \in M_{mn}$ then there exists an $A$ that is a zero matrix such that $Ax$ will result in the zero vector being in $U$. I don't know if this is correct but this is all I could come up with.

for closure under addition, $A_1x$ and $A_2x$ are in $U$ then $A_1x +A_2x $ must be in $U$ as well since $A$ is an $m*n$ matrix and $A_1 + A_2$ should result in an $m\times n$ matrix as well which should be in $U$ from $x(A_1 + A_2)$

For scalar multiplication closure, I have zero idea on what to do.

Comment: @DonAntonio Look at the definition of $U$ again...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show $0_{m \times 1} \in U$, note that $0_{m \times 1} = 0_{m \times n}x$.

Note taht matrix multiplication is not commutative, that is  in general, we do not have $AB=BA$.

To prove closure under addition, $A_1x+A_2x = (A_1+A_2)x$, note that it is not equal to $x(A_1+A_2)$.

To prove closure under scalar multiplication, suppose $v= Ax$, note that $(kv)=(kA)x$, we have $kA \in M_{m \times n}$.